# Difference between delete statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DELETE a
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.Field1 = b.Field1 AND a.Field2 = b.Field2;
```

vs.

```
DELETE
FROM TableA
WHERE Field1 IN (
    SELECT Field1
    FROM TableB
) AND Field2 IN (
    SELECT Field2
    FROM TableB
);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The first delete statement is more precise because Field1 and Field2 must match within the same row of TableB. The second delete statement could delete unexpected rows because Field1 and Field2 could match across different rows in TableB.

Comment: @DaleK the difference between the two queries

Comment: What about the difference are you unable to work out? Are you asking if they delete different records? If they perform differently? Whats the context? How did you come across 2 queries that you are unsure of? Whats the actual end goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logical conditions of the two statements are different.

The first statement will delete any row in `TableA` if both it's `Field1` and `Field2` correspond to the equivalent columns of a row in `TableB`.

The second statement will delete any row in `TableA` if the value of `Field1` exists in `Field1` of `TableB`, and the value of `Field2` exists in `Field2` of `TableB` - but that doesn't have to be in the same row.

It's easy to see the difference if you change the `delete` to `select`.

Here's an example. First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```sql
CREATE TABLE A 
(
    AInt int,
    AChar char(1)
);

CREATE TABLE B
(
    BInt int,
    BChar char(1)
);

INSERT INTO A (AInt, AChar) VALUES
(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'),
(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b');


INSERT INTO B (BInt, BChar) VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(2, 'b'),
(3, 'c');
```

The statements (translated to `select` statements):

```sql
SELECT A.*
FROM A
JOIN B 
    ON AInt = BInt AND AChar = BChar;


SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE AInt IN (
    SELECT BInt
    FROM B
) AND AChar IN (
    SELECT BChar
    FROM B
);
```

Results:

```
AInt    AChar
1       a
2       b


AInt    AChar
1       a
2       a
3       a
1       b
2       b
3       b
```

And you can see a live demo on [<kbd>DB<>Fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9680c0b0cb0ef11876ca1ac516acbe4f)